# How to delay window opening

Tags: html

I couldn't figure out how to delay a page from opening for a designated period of time using HTML. I will be having 30-40 windows open and close at different intervals for a video web piece. Here is what I have in order to close the window, I just can't seem to figure out how to delay it from opening.

```
<script>

    var SubWin = window.open("Sub.html","-","width=300,height=180,top=0,left=00,scrollbars=no");

    setTimeout(function(){Subwin.close() },50000);

</script>
```

Comment: You didn't try this? `setTimeout(function() { window.open("Sub.html") }, 1000);`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not define the open function using a timeout?

```
var SubWin = setTimeout(function () {
    window.open("Sub.html", "-", "width=300, height=180, top=0, left=00, scrollbars=no");

    setTimeout(function () {
        Subwin.close()
    }, 50000);
}, 1000);
```